# TypeError: carouselImages[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm still trying to get an image slider to work. I have a some JavaScript code that won't function.

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


// Counter
let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px';
```

after that are the button listeners, but they work fine.
I'm constantly getting the error TypeError: carouselImages[0] is undefined.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Do ```console.log(carouselImages)``` and see whether you have the data inside before doing ```carouselImages[0]``` ..

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `carouselImages` has no elements inside of it, because there are no elements that much your selection `.carousel-slide img`. Therefore, `carouselImages[0]` is undefined.

Comment: I have images that a loaded in before from a different JavaScript file. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Run this javascript file afterwards. You have to make sure that there are elements matching the CSS query `.carousel-slide img`

Comment: I'm running the first script in the head and this one in the in the body, but I'm still getting this error. I've also added a defer tag to this one.